# Upgrade fails: "Could not delete core"

Tags: composer, upgrading, 10

The upgrade from 9.5.11 to 10.1.7 fails with the error: *Upgrade of drupal/core failed; Could not delete core*
I followed the steps in https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/how-to-upgrade-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10
The step *composer update --dry-run* gives no errors.
What should I do?
(btw: a few days ago I tested the proces with a demo-version of the site and everything worked fine; although the upgrade then was to 10.1.6)

```
[u134858p129517@web0137 public_html]$ ls -la
totaal 30480
dr-xr-xr-x 11 u134858p129517 u134858p129517     4096 27 apr  2022 .
drwx--x--x  7 u134858p129517 u134858p129517     4096 19 feb  2022 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 u134858p129517 u134858p129517      312 12 dec 10:06 autoload.php
-rw-r--r--  1 u134858p129517 u134858p129517     4085 12 dec 10:17 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 u134858p129517 u134858p129517   219854 12 dec 10:26 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx  2 u134858p129517 u134858p129517     4096 12 dec 10:27 core
-rw-r--r--  1 u134858p129517 u134858p129517     1025 20 sep 13:42 .csslintrc
```

. . . .

```
[u134858p129517@web0137 public_html]$ ls -la core
totaal 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 u134858p129517 u134858p129517 4096 12 dec 10:27 .
dr-xr-xr-x 11 u134858p129517 u134858p129517 4096 27 apr  2022 ..
[u134858p129517@web0137 public_html]$
```

Comment: Make sure the user executing `composer` has write permissions over the web root

Comment: The directory is empty, which is just...interesting. But the parent directory is unwritable and that is why Composer cannot remove the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `core` directory or its parent directory is unwritable by the shell user. Make the directory and its parent directory writable by the shell user to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
I checked the permissions on the core directory and they were OK. As the website had to be brought life again, I restored a backup (Drupal 9.5.11) and repeated the proces on a 100% copy of the website. This time without any errors. 
I will run the upgrade proces on the production site in a few days (need to plan this first). Hopefully this time without errors.

Comment: The permissions were not ok. There is no other way this could have happened.

Comment: Thanks again for your support. And I don't mean to be stubborn, but running the process another time gives the same error.
These are the permissions at the start of the update process:
drwxrwxrwx  2 u134858p129517 u134858p129517     4096 12 dec 10:27 core ...

I sure hope you can tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Add the output of `ls -la core` to the Question.

Comment: Btw, the map core is empty

Comment: Add information to the Question.

Comment: Hope this works better

Comment: My answer remains accurate.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks a million. I should have read your first answer better. Not the permissions of the map core were inadequate but the permissions of the parent directory.